# Rails 3 - create and save object with hidden fields by value from params  - 'Called id for nil' error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, hidden-field

In my application i have controller which receive value from params. After that i should use this value to save object (i use hidden field). But i receive such error: `Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id` when i push `Create` button. How can i solve this?

Controller:

```
# encoding: UTF-8
class AttendancesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_teachers, :only => [ :new, :create ]

  def new
    @teacher_subjects = current_user.teacher.subjects
    @pupil = get_pupil_from_params( params )
    @attendance = Attendance.new
  end

  def create
    @teacher_subjects = current_user.teacher.subjects
    @attendance = Attendance.new( params[:attendance] )

    if @attendance.save
      redirect_to journals_path( :class_code => params[:class_code],
                                   :subject_name => params[:subject_name] )
      flash[:success] = "Success!"
    else
      flash.now[:error] = @attendance.errors.full_messages
                                      .to_sentence :last_word_connector => ", ",
                                                   :two_words_connector => ", "
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private

    def get_pupil_from_params( params )
      pupil = Pupil.where( "id = ?", params[:p_id] ).first
    end    
end
```

View

```
<%= form_for @attendance, :html => {:class => "form-horizontal"} do |f| %>
  <%= field_set_tag do %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :class_code, params[:class_code] %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :subject_name, params[:subject_name] %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :pupil_id, :value => @pupil.id %>

    <div class="control-group">
      <%= f.label :visited, "Did pupil visit lesson?", :class => "control-label" %>
      <div class="controls">
        <%= label_tag nil, nil, :class => "radio" do %>
          <%= f.radio_button :visited, true %>
          Yes
        <% end %>

        <%= label_tag nil, nil, :class => "radio" do %>
          <%= f.radio_button :visited, false %>
          No
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>

    <%= f.submit "Create", :class => "btn btn-large btn-success" %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

After i push 'Create' button i get such hash:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"kgNoJfivDEzqpLJYF5QK9vQS99Cq9app5ujPDC4lKKI=",
 "class_code"=>"11v",
 "subject_name"=>"Math",
 "attendance"=>{"pupil_id"=>"1"},
 "commit"=>"Create"}
```

My model:

```
class Attendance < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :pupil
  belongs_to :lesson

  validates :pupil_id, :presence => { :message => "should exist" }

  validates :lesson_id, :presence => { :message => "should exist" }

  validates :visited,
              :inclusion => { :in => [true, false],
                              :message => "should be chosen"
                            }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If the attendance fails to save you will try to re-render the form with errors but you don't set the value of `@pupil` in the `create` method of your controller - so it will be `nil` when `@pupil.id` is called in the view.

This may be your problem here, however to be sure we need to know if `Attendance` has any validations and we need to see the line number of the exception - so if this isn't the problem please post them!

Comment: Looks to me like your attendance will fail to save because it doesn't have a lesson id set...